# Spring boot web application is working in embed tomcat but not in external

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

Spring-boot web application is running great in embed tomcat with HTTPS protocol.
The same was build as a war file and deployed to an external tomcat but it is not working now giving a 404 error.

How do I run the external tomcat in HTTPS protocol, I have tried uncommenting the SSL host config in server.xml but there is no use.

Answer (score -1):

To disable HTTPS in spring project, you can add below property in application.properties
`server.ssl.enabled=false`

Comment: I have tried this, not working facing the same 404 error. Even though if it worked, I have to work with HTTPS only

Comment: is deployment successful?,or  are there any errors in deployment ?

Comment: able to deploy successfully

Comment: can you share how are you trying to access application, e.g, accessing services via postman or curl commands

Comment: Since it is a web application am directly using  http://loclhost:8080/ in the browser by deploying the project into tomcat